# Drupal view taking too long to load

Tags: javascript, ajax, drupal

I developed a site in drupal and for the most part all of the pages in the site load just fine, except for one page which takes an average  of 2.8 seconds to load. This is obviously not expectable but I was fairly new to drupal when that section of the site was developed.

The site is in testing and can be viewed now @ xltrust.mayaco.com/properties

Right now it is loading everything into the dom. So all of the properties, information, images, and google map. Is there a way to only have what is needed for that page to load and then when one of the properties is clicked on then and only then would the properties images, map, etc load. Instead of everything loading when a user first goes to the page.

Comment: that page won't even load for me. check what data the view is using, it might be pulling in a lot of content from the database, maybe you can make this leaner. how does it work with caching enabled?

Comment: @MattSaunders Yes, it is loading a lot of data from the database. So it is loading all of the images, and actual content that is related to the properties. I have cleared the cache and minified my js and css files but it didn't do much.

Comment: very strange. would you mind giving me temporary access to take a look at the view?

Comment: Yes it is strange but the code to make this work is pretty crazy... I wouldn't be able to give you access but you can view the source code on my bitbucket I would need to give you access to that via an email add. @MattSaunders. But right now there are a total of 3 views that are being used. 1 view to generate the Table of states, 2 view to hold the map, 3 view for the properties detals and light box details.

Answer (score -1):

hey everyone who tried to answer this question.

i am the new developer that took this persons job. i have rewrote the entire page he was trying to fix. now everything works...his problem was loading 1000000000000+ photos / google maps on initial load. i stripped everything out and process it all on the fly with an ajax request. site speed ~ 2 seconds to load up. load a map ~3 seconds to fetch the map initially then it just shows the old on when clicked again.

EDIT::
ooh yeah i also remade the map functionality no more images on that. now it is a vector map recoded to work with my new functionality. i basically took the dev package of jqvmap.com
and hacked the sh!t out of it. binding in my function calls on click. yeah the other developer elodev. was a newbie. entry level very eager to learn to i hear. i just hope he checks this feed again. i'd like to let him know where he went wrong. not to gloat. but to teach.